# WordPress taxonomy images plugin displaying all terms

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I am using taxonomy-images/ WordPress plugin (https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/)

Target: I have got a poster taxonomy and I would like to display term name and term image. I would like to be able to display, retrieve ALL terms in my taxonomy, no matter term name is empty.

Issue: But if both data are not entered I can not display the term. I am not managing to correctly make use of 'hide_empty'.

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: gof Poster Home Page */

// https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/
?>


<?php
$taxonomy     = 'month-category';
$orderby      = 'name';
$order        = 'ASC'; 
$show_count   = false;
$pad_counts   = false;
$hierarchical = true;
$hide_empty   = false; 
$title      = '';
$images     = 'image_id';

$args = array(
  'taxonomy'  = $taxonomy,
  'orderby'      = $orderby,
  'order'        = $order,
  'show_count'   = $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   = $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' = $hierarchical,
  'hide_empty'   = $hide_empty,
  'title_li'     = $title
);

//$terms = get_terms( 'month-category', $args );
// $terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', 'month-category', $args);
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', $args);

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $count = count( $terms );
    $i = 0;
    $term_list = '<div id="poster-cat-wrapper">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
      $term_list .= 
      '<div class="poster-cat">' .
        '<a href="/posters/?gof=' . $term->name . '">' .
          wp_get_attachment_image( $term->$images, 'detail' ) .
          '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>' .
        '</a>' .
      '</div>';
        $i++;        
        // '<a href="/posters/?gof=' . $term->name . '">' . $term-&gt;name . '</a>'
        if ( $count != $i ) {
            $term_list .= ' ';
        }
        else {
            $term_list .= '</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot figure out how to do this either, but I found a nasty hack. Look for this part in 'public-filters.php' in '/plugins/taxonomy-images/':

```
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
    'cache_images'  => true,
    'having_images' => true,
    'taxonomy'      => 'category',
    'term_args'     => array('hide_empty' => false),
) );
```

Change it to this:

```
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
    'cache_images'  => true,
    'having_images' => true,
    'taxonomy'      => 'category',
    'term_args'     => array('hide_empty' => false),
) );
```

Once again: Know that this is NOT the right solution! You should write a filter that does this for you. Every plugin update will break this functionality.